# detect if user is active or idle

Tags: javascript, events

I'm building a browser extension and want to detect if the user is active.
Therefore I check, if the user moved the mouse for the past 2min.

However for better results I would like to track multiple events at the same time. Does the user moved the mouse, made a clicked event or scrolled during the last two minutes.

Here is my code to detect the mouse movement:

```
document.onmousemove = function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    // user is idle
  }, 120000);
};
```

how can I evolve the code to track multiple events at once?

Comment: Attach similar event handlers to onscroll and onclick? I find it very hard to click or scroll without moving the mouse though. Care to explain what you will do when you detect that the user has been idle for 2mins? Maybe there's other solutions.

Comment: so define a function and have all the events call that function....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
var timeout;
function idle(){
  //idle things
}
document.onmousemove = function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(idle(), 120000);
};
document.onscroll = function() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(idle(), 120000);
};
//continue with other events
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using threads js library:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/threads@VERSION/dist/threads.browser.min.js"></script>
```

And try something like this:

```
thread
  .send({ string : 'mousemovement' })
  // The handlers come here: (none of them is mandatory)
  .on('mousemovement', function(response) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
     timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        // user is idle
     }, 120000);
    thread.kill();
    })
  .on('scroll', function(response) {
    //Do something
    thread.kill();
  });
```

That code is just an example, please read more here if you want to try this method: https://www.npmjs.com/package/threads

Is just an option to handle multiple tasks at the same time